# Objdump for ARM64 Architecture

Tags: assembly, arm64, objdump, binutils, ctf

I’ve encountered this error in Ubuntu with ARM64 (aarch64) architecture where Objdump doesnt wan’t to run.
The error message for the following command «objdump -d filename»:

```
filename: file format elf64-little
objdump: can’t disassemble for architecture UNKNOWN!
```

Im not sure if objdump even runs on Aarch64 architecture. Does anyone have any ideas? Or is there any other command to disassembly an ETF file?

Comment: Yes objdump works fine with aarch64. What do you get for `file filename`?

Comment: @Jester thanks for the reply. file filename outputs:
filename: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=....., for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, with debug_info, not stripped

Comment: So that's an x86-64 binary not an aarch64. You will need the x86-64 objdump for that (can be cross compiled to run on aarch64 if that's what you have).

Comment: @Jester any idea on what the easiest way to do this is?

Comment: Easiest? If you do not have access to x86-64 system or an already compiled x86-64 version of objdump then install qemu and download a ubuntu image you can boot. If you have a C environment set up and you can compile stuff, then compiling binutils for yourself is a simple matter as it does not have many dependencies and isn't too big either. I have compiled it for like a dozen different architectures.

Comment: Easiest way is to use `llvm-objdump -d`; LLVM can (and does) build support for multiple targets into one build of the tools.  `llvm-objdump` will simply auto-detect the architecture and disassemble.  (`clang` compiles for whatever target is was configured to use as the default, normally the native one.  But `clang -target mips` works, for example, at least for stuff that doesn't need MIPS-specific headers.)

Answer (score 0):

GNU Binutils can only handle the one architecture chosen at build time.  On an AArch64 Linux system, the system `objdump` command will be configured for aarch64-linux-gnu object files, which this isn't.  If you had an `x86-64-linux-gnu-objdump` cross-toolchain installed, you could use that.

But you probably do already have a disassembler installed that can handle a variety of architectures:
**`llvm-objdump -d`**

LLVM can (and does) build support for multiple targets into one build of the tools. `llvm-objdump` will simply auto-detect the architecture and disassemble. (`clang` compiles for whatever target is was configured to use as the default, normally the native one. But `clang -c -target mips` works, for example, at least for stuff that doesn't need MIPS-specific headers or a library to link against.)